# How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, arrays, max

I have a simple JavaScript Array object containing a few numbers.

```
[267, 306, 108]
```

Is there a function that would find the largest number in this array?

Comment: `Math.max(...[267, 306, 108]);`

Answer (score 324, accepted):

[Resig to the rescue:](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
```

**Warning**: since [the maximum number of arguments is as low as 65535 on some VMs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions), use a for loop if you're not certain the array is that small.

Comment: Christ. 90 rep in 3 minutes for an answer that would have been faster to google.

Comment: Ah, but now it has the **SO Sticker of Quality** affixed to it in an only slightly-crooked fashion!

Comment: FWIW, if performance is a factor in your solution, I would **test that** compared to your own easily-coded function to make sure it performs well. We tend to assume that the native implementation will be faster; in fact, the cost of the `apply` call can wash that out very easily.

Comment: By the way, this only works reliably with number values (not, say, string ones), whereas `sort` -based solution works with strings and objects.

Comment: @kangax: on the other hand, if you have a mix of numbers and string representations of numbers, the `sort()` -based method *may* not do what you expect. Try: `["7", "50", 300]`...

Comment: What if my array length is bigger than parameter count limit ?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: what is the parameter count limit? And is it part of the ECMAScript standard or a particular implementation (i.e. V8)?

Comment: @CrescentFresh according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply it is hardcoded to 65535. According to this: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=172 and by knowledge that arguments are pushed onto stack we know that it's not unlimited

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: nice references. Evidently the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @CrescentFresh I was very interested in this topic so I posted my own answer and provided link to testing for a limit. Of course I may be wrong! But your method despite being elegant, fails with very big arrays. That's just a note :)

Comment: Whilst this solution is elegant unfortunately it perfoms much worse than a simple loop with a comparison. Here's a test that compares the various alternatives: http://jsperf.com/finding-maximum-element-in-an-array

Comment: @Quasimondo: yes the cost of `apply` is high as T.J. Crowder points out.

Comment: Also, this method is not robust. It fails if your array is larger than the the mamximum stack size resulting in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Comment: @MarkLundin: raised by [@lukas.pukenis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19167520/45433) two year ago

Comment: @CrescentFresh The answer can be updated for new `ECMAScript 6` spread operator.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies here if the array is empty. E.g. `Math.max([]) = 0` while `Math.max.apply(Math, []) = -Infinity`

Comment: @AndreasFinne: `Math.max([])` [isn't a thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). You pass arguments separately. You do not bundle them up into a single array argument.

Comment: Note that you can also do this: `Math.max.apply(this, array)`

Answer (score 208):

You can use the apply function, to call [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
var array = [267, 306, 108];
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, array); // 306
```

How does it work?

The [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function is used to call another function, with a given context and arguments, provided as an array. The min and max functions can take an arbitrary number of input arguments: Math.max(val1, val2, ..., valN)

So if we call:

```
Math.min.apply(Math, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

The apply function will execute:

```
Math.min(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Note that the first parameter, the context, is not important for these functions since they are static. They will work regardless of what is passed as the context.

Comment: Whoa you put on your answers with a lot of effort :D

Comment: That's great. But what if my array length exceeds parameter size limit(of function)? What then ?

Comment: I like this answer better than the others because it explains what everything does and why. +1

Answer (score 66):

The easiest syntax, with the new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max(...arr);
```

Source : [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: _However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements_
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: @Green FWIW, the parameter count limit is 65536 (at least on Chrome) ([source(https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80797)]). So if your array has more than 65536 elements, this answer won't work.

Comment: *65536 ought to be enough for anybody*

Answer (score 48):

I'm not a JavaScript expert, but I wanted to see how these methods stack up, so this was good practice for me. I don't know if this is technically the right way to performance test these, but I just ran them one right after another, as you can see in my code.

Sorting and getting the 0th value is by far the worst method (and it modifies the order of your array, which may not be desirable). For the others, the difference is negligible unless you're talking millions of indices.

**Average results of five runs with a 100,000-index array of random numbers:**

- reduce took **4.0392 ms** to run
- Math.max.apply took **3.3742 ms** to run
- sorting and getting the 0th value took **67.4724 ms** to run
- Math.max within reduce() took **6.5804 ms** to run
- custom findmax function took **1.6102 ms** to run

---

```
var performance = window.performance

function findmax(array)
{
    var max = 0,
        a = array.length,
        counter

    for (counter=0; counter<a; counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] > max)
        {
            max = array[counter]
        }
    }
    return max
}

function findBiggestNumber(num) {
  var counts = []
  var i
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      counts.push(Math.random())
  }

  var a, b

  a = performance.now()
  var biggest = counts.reduce(function(highest, count) {
        return highest > count ? highest : count
      }, 0)
  b = performance.now()
  console.log('reduce took ' + (b - a) + ' ms to run')

  a = performance.now()
  var biggest2 = Math.max.apply(Math, counts)
  b = performance.now()
  console.log('Math.max.apply took ' + (b - a) + ' ms to run')

  a = performance.now()
  var biggest3 = counts.sort(function(a,b) {return b-a;})[0]
  b = performance.now()
  console.log('sorting and getting the 0th value took ' + (b - a) + ' ms to run')

  a = performance.now()
  var biggest4 = counts.reduce(function(highest, count) {
        return Math.max(highest, count)
      }, 0)
  b = performance.now()
  console.log('Math.max within reduce() took ' + (b - a) + ' ms to run')

  a = performance.now()
  var biggest5 = findmax(counts)
  b = performance.now()
  console.log('custom findmax function took ' + (b - a) + ' ms to run')
  console.log(biggest + '-' + biggest2 + '-' + biggest3 + '-' + biggest4 + '-' + biggest5)

}

findBiggestNumber(1E5)
```

Comment: For me, this is the best answer for this question.

Comment: I've made [`jsperf tests`](https://jsperf.com/js-find-largest-number) for the above

Answer (score 38):

I've found that for bigger arrays (~100k elements), it actually pays to simply iterate the array with a humble `for` loop, performing ~30% better than `Math.max.apply()`:

```
function mymax(a)
{
    var m = -Infinity, i = 0, n = a.length;

    for (; i != n; ++i) {
        if (a[i] > m) {
            m = a[i];
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

[**Benchmark results**](http://jsperf.com/max-integer-from-array)

Comment: FWIW, comes out to 84% now on Chrome 31.

Answer (score 33):

You could sort the array in descending order and get the first item:

```
[267, 306, 108].sort(function(a,b){return b-a;})[0]
```

Comment: I would assume you could also just sort and get the last item...?

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, but you would need to specify the comparison function on your own: `sort(function(a,b){return b-a;})`

Comment: Ah. I was thinking more like: `[...].sort().pop()`

Comment: @Shog9: Nice, didn’t think of that.

Comment: +1 this is very usefull in case you have more then one highest number into the array! ;) very nice Shog9 & Gumbo

Comment: "finding the number takes order-n, sorting takes between order(n log n) to order(n squared), dependig on the sort algorithm used" - http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/382.htm

Comment: Also keep in mind that this sorts the array, which may or may not be a desired side effect. The apply solution is better performing and has no side effects.

Comment: @vsync what? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) says it's in place. So does a quick check in the browser console.

Answer (score 31):

Use:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var largest = arr.reduce(function(x,y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
});

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: Had I see this answer first (currently at the bottom of the list) I would have saved two hours.

Comment: The Math.max approach is probably the most standard, but I was getting a stack overflow when the array was too large (500K). This answer is fast and efficient and is the one I ended up using myself, so I'm upvoting this one.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
[0,1,2,3,4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
  return Math.max(previousValue,currentValue);
});
```

Comment: Initial value should be set to `-Infinity`.

Comment: @Jack, why is this needed? even with an array of all negative numbers, I get a valid result.

Comment: It's the edge case whereby the array is empty.

Answer (score 7):

To find the largest number in an array you just need to use `Math.max(...arrayName);`. It works like this:

```
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(Math.max(...myArr));
```

To learn more about `Math.max`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 5):

Almost all of the answers use `Math.max.apply()` which is nice and dandy, but it has limitations.

Function arguments are placed onto the stack which has a downside - a limit. So if your array is bigger than the limit it will fail with `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

To find a call stack size I used this code:

```
var ar = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 100*99999; i++) {
  ar.push(1);
  try {
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, ar);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Limit reached: '+i+' error is: '+e);
    break;
  }
}
```

It proved to be biggest on Firefox on my machine - **591519**. This means that if you array contains more than **591519** items, `Math.max.apply()` will result in **RangeError**.

The best solution for this problem is iterative way (credit: https://developer.mozilla.org/):

```
max = -Infinity, min = +Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] > max)
    max = numbers[i];
  if (numbers[i] < min)
    min = numbers[i];
}
```

I have written about this question on my blog [here](http://www.letsdive.in/2013/10/03/finding-biggest-number-in-big-array/).

Comment: This is not fair. I want the answer right here, on SO, not another link to another third-party resource. Especially when it's combined with "everything here is bad, but go, look, it's so great on my blog..."

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy a link to a third party works very well in case it's updated with new insigths and solutions. Also no need to feel offended. People just want to solve your problems too. I wanted to solve it too, so I wrote about it on my blog

Answer (score 5):

Finding max and min value the easy and manual way. This code is much faster than `Math.max.apply`; I have tried up to 1000k numbers in array.

```
function findmax(array)
{
    var max = 0;
    var a = array.length;
    for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] > max)
        {
            max = array[counter];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

function findmin(array)
{
    var min = array[0];
    var a = array.length;
    for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] < min)
        {
            min = array[counter];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: `findmax()` gives the wrong result if there are only negative numbers in the array; `findmin()` gives the wrong result for an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```js
const inputArray = [ 1, 3, 4, 9, 16, 2, 20, 18];
const maxNumber = Math.max(...inputArray);
console.log(maxNumber);
```

Comment: _However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements_
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 5):

Simple one liner

```
[].sort().pop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course there exists `Math.max.apply(null,[23,45,67,-45])`  and the result is to return `67`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the wrap can be done with `Function.prototype.bind`, giving you an "all-native" *function*.

```
var aMax = Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, Math);
aMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also extend `Array` to have this function and make it part of every array.

```
Array.prototype.max = function(){return Math.max.apply( Math, this )};
myArray = [1,2,3];

console.log( myArray.max() );
```

Comment: Terribly inefficient.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, thank you, I agree. Original answer was not a good solution. Sort by default does not sort numbers, it treats elements as strings. Edited my answer to have the right sort.

Comment: That was not my point. Sorting an Array to find the maximum is per se terribly inefficient, since it takes at least N log N operations, whereas finding the maximum can be done in N operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var maximum = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

var array = [-3, -2, 217, 9, -8, 46];
array.forEach(function(value){
  if(value > maximum) {
    maximum = value;
  }
});

console.log(maximum); // 217
```

Answer (score 1):

Using - `Array.prototype.reduce()` is cool!

`[267, 306, 108].reduce((acc,val)=> (acc>val)?acc:val)`

where **acc = accumulator** and **val = current value**;

```js
var a = [267, 306, 108].reduce((acc,val)=> (acc>val)?acc:val);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
var arr = [267, 306, 108];
var largestNum = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] > largest){
     var largest = arr[i];
   }
}
console.log(largest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started with JavaScript, but I think this method would be good:

```
var array = [34, 23, 57, 983, 198];
var score = 0;

for(var i = 0; i = array.length; i++) {
  if(array[ i ] > score) {
    score = array[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: This will have trouble if `array` contains only negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach on how to do it using ternary operators

```js
const findMax = (arr, max, i) => arr.length === i ? max :
  findMax(arr, arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max, ++i)

const arr = [5, 34, 2, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3];
const max = findMax(arr, arr[0], 0)
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var nums = [1,4,5,3,1,4,7,8,6,2,1,4];
nums.sort();
nums.reverse();
alert(nums[0]);
```

Simplest Way:

```
var nums = [1,4,5,3,1,4,7,8,6,2,1,4]; nums.sort(); nums.reverse(); alert(nums[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Find the largest number in a multidimensional array

```
var max = [];

for(var i=0; arr.length>i; i++ ) {

   var arra = arr[i];
   var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arra);
   max.push(largest);
}
return max;
```

Comment: It is always advisable to add some elaborate explanation to your code, especially if there are already multiple other answers. Why is this one different/better?

Comment: @Bowdzone ,thanks for the comment. this way is very basic what makes it simple to understand with a little knowledge of just few methods.

Comment: This doesn't return the largest number, it returns an array of the largest number of each array in the multidimensional array. You would need to add e.g. `var tmax = Math.max.apply(Math, max)`, or better yet, use a closure of a loop function e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980012/7438857. With this modification, it is better answered to a separate question, how do you "find the largest number in a multidimensional array", or at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616910/find-largest-number-in-a-2d-array-in-javascript. WIP: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesray/3cLu9for/8/.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617019/7438857 is a better answer to the right question, while this answer doesn't answer the above question, it returns the largest number in each array within a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
Array.prototype.max = function(){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, this );
};
```

And now try `[3,10,2].max()` returns `10`

Answer (score 0):

**Find Max and Min value using Bubble Sort**

```js
    var arr = [267, 306, 108];

    for(i=0, k=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if(arr[i]>arr[j]) {
          k = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = k;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('largest Number: '+ arr[0]);
    console.log('Smallest Number: '+ arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: (1) Javascript arrays already have a O(n log n) sort function. (2) Bubble sort is O(n^2). (3) Finding the min and max is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function largestNum(arr) {
  var currentLongest = arr[0]

  for (var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] > currentLongest){
      currentLongest = arr[i]
    }
  }

  return currentLongest
}
```

Comment: Is this answer substantially different from many of the others on this page?

Answer (score 0):

As per @Quasimondo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array/54980012#comment31228741_1379556), which seems to have been largely missed, the below seems to have the best performance as shown here: https://jsperf.com/finding-maximum-element-in-an-array. Note that while for the array in the question, performance may not have a significant effect, for large arrays performance becomes more important, and again [as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array#comment28352416_1379556) using `Math.max()` doesn't even work if the array length is more than 65535. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167520/7438857).

```
function largestNum(arr) {
    var d = data;
    var m = d[d.length - 1];
    for (var i = d.length - 1; --i > -1;) {
      if (d[i] > m) m = d[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One `for/of` loop solution:

```js
const numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 80, 56, 10];


const findMax = (...numbers) => {
  let currentMax = numbers[0]; // 2

  for (const number of numbers) {
    if (number > currentMax) {
      console.log(number, currentMax);
      currentMax = number;
    }
  }
  console.log('Largest ', currentMax);
  return currentMax;
};

findMax(...numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solution to return largest numbers in arrays.**

```
const largestOfFour = arr => {
    let arr2 = [];
    arr.map(e => {
        let numStart = -Infinity;
        e.forEach(num => {
            if (num > numStart) {
                numStart = num;

            }
        })
        arr2.push(numStart);
    })
    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be quite simple:

```
var countArray = [1,2,3,4,5,1,3,51,35,1,357,2,34,1,3,5,6];

var highestCount = 0;
for(var i=0; i<=countArray.length; i++){    
    if(countArray[i]>=highestCount){
    highestCount = countArray[i]
  }
}

console.log("Highest Count is " + highestCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

highest and smallest value using sort with arrow function

```js
var highest=[267, 306, 108,700,490,678,355,399,500,800].sort((a,b)=>{return b-a;})[0]
console.log(highest)
var smallest=[267, 306, 108,700,490,678,355,399,500,800].sort((a,b)=>{return a-b;})[0]
console.log(smallest)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [267, 306, 108]
let longest = Math.max(...array);
```