# Finding Elements in an Array that are larger than those in another Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, underscore.js

There are 2 arrays `data1` and `data2`. The desired result is an array containing all the elements in `data1` which are larger than the largest element in `data2` [+ the 3 before as defined in variable `buffer`]. *In other words, the  result should also include the previous 3 elements in `data1` preceding the matched elements.* Both arrays are already sorted in ascending order.

My code below does what is required, but is there a better way to do the same thing? Will regex be faster?

**Data set**

```
data1 = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]
data2 = [102, 104, 106, 108]
buffer = 3
```

The desired result is `[106, 107, 108, 109, 110]`

**Algorithm**

```
largestData2 = _.max(data2)
data1LargerThanData2 = _.filter(data1, function(data1) {
    return data1 > largestData2
})
smallestData1LargerThanData2 = _.min(data1LargerThanData2)

sliceStart = data1.indexOf(smallestData1LargerThanData2) - buffer
result = data1.slice(sliceStart)
```

Comment: @KevinB I want all the elements in `data1` than are larger than any of the elements in `data2`, so I guess I will look for the largest element in `data2` to compare with all the elements from `data1`

Comment: @KevinB I'm also looking to include 3 other elements from `data1` than comes before `[106,107]`. Sorry I didnt explain it clearly, I have a variable `buffer = 3` which i used to find `sliceStart`

Comment: @KevinB Ah I guess you are right, its a wording problem. Let me edit the question

Comment: It currently outputs the correct result `[106, 107, 108, 109, 110]`

Answer (score 1):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z222T/2/)***

```
var data1 = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
data2 = [102, 104, 106, 108];
var maxData2 = Math.max.apply(Math, data2);

var newData = [];
data1.map(function(val) {
    if(val > maxData2) {
        newData.push(val);
    }
});
var index = data1.indexOf(newData[0]); //getting index of 1st element

var prev3Arr = [data1[index-3], data1[index-2], data1[index-1]]; //forming prev 3 elements

var finalResult = $.merge( prev3Arr, newData); // merging both arrays

console.log(finalResult);
```

Check your console for result: `[106, 107, 108, 109, 110]`

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the largest value in `data2`:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, data2);
```

Then get all of the numbers from `data1` that are greater than `max`:

```
var arr = data1.filter(function (el) {
  return el > max;
});
```

Use value of the first value in `arr` to find our starting point in `data1` and take the appropriate chunk of elements from it.

```
var index = data1.indexOf(arr[0]) - 3;
var chunk = data1.slice(index, index + 3);
```

Merge `arr` into `chunk`.

```
chunk.push.apply(chunk, arr); // chunk = [106, 107, 108, 109, 110]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGMSF/22/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the arrays are always in order:

```
var result;
var largestData2 = data2.slice( -1 );

_.each( data1, function( x, index ){
    if( x  > largestData2 ){
        result = data1.slice( index - buffer - 1 );
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two arrays are sorted ascending, you can omit `max` and just pick the last element

```
var largestData2 = data2[data2.length - 1];
```

To find the position in `data1` being larger than `largest_data2`, you can use a binary search and then go back three elements

```
var smallestData1LargerThanData2Index = binarySearch(data1, largestData2);
var sliceStart = smallestData1LargerThanData2Index - buffer;
if (sliceStart < 0)
    sliceStart = 0;

var result = data1.slice(sliceStart);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN6jg/)

*Update:*

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN6jg/2/) to actually use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

You want all the values from data1 that are larger than the largest value of data2? If so [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array) this might help