# Whats wrong with this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Largest number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>largest number</h2>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/Javascript">

            function Max(num1,num2,num3)
            {
               var largest=arguments[num1,num2,num3]
               for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
               {
                  if((num1>num2)&&(num1>num3))
                      largest=num1
                  else if((num2>num1)&&(num2>num3))
                      largest=num2
                  else
                      largest=num3
               }
               return(largest)
            }
            document.write("</br>")
            var num1 = prompt("Enter first number"," ")
            var num2 = prompt("Enter second number"," ")
            var num3 = prompt("Enter third number"," ")
            var large = Max(num1,num2,num3)
            document.write("You entered",num1,",",num2,",",num3)
            document.write("</br>")
            document.write("The largest number is :",large)
        </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This program accepts 3 numbers through prompt. Only for specific numbers it gives strange and unexpected output. If I give input for this program as 5,21 and 100 when each prompt appears, the output will be given 5 as a largest number. Even for the input 10,24 and 5, the output will be 5.

Is there any problem while using if condition or array.

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure your numbers are actually numbers, and not strings. Question, what's this `arguments[num1,num2,num3]`? What happened to the indentation and semicolons?

Comment: Also be careful because javascript has a built in method called max.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms: It doesn't. It has an object `Math` with a method `max`. Won't interfere, although it is probably not useful...

Comment: OP see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: parseInt() your input values.

Comment: @elclanrs ah, my mistake, thanks for the clarification. I saw the syntax highlighting, did a quick google search and did not pay attention to the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually passing numbers to the function. [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) values are stored as strings.

Lexicographically, "5" is greater than "100" since "5" comes after "1".

You need to use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to ensure integers are passed in, or if you allow decimal values, then [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
var large = Max(parseInt(num1, 10), parseInt(num2, 10), parseInt(num3, 10));
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZDTA/1/)

You may wish to do the number parsing within the `Max()` function to ensure that the arguments are always integers.

Also, the initial assignment of `arguments[num1, num2, num3]` to `largest` doesn't make sense. The variable just needs to be declared. You also have an unnecessary loop in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Another example related to this could be

```
var myArray = [45,50,2,99,0];
var result = Math.max.apply(Math,myArray);
document.write("Max value is = "+result );
```

Hope its solve your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First of all, you shouldn't try to access multiple values inside the `arguments`, especially not by values instead of indexes.

```
var largest;
```

should be enough in your case.
Next, you are running a for loop multiple times for absolutely no purpose, since you're checking the condition already. Decide if you want to use a for look or chained else/if statements. Also, by looking at your code, it looks like you want to make this function accept as many parameters as you want, and this implementation of yours does not support that. So, here is a fixed version of the code that should work with just about any number of parameters (more than 0).

```
function Max(){
    var largest;
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        var intval = parseInt(arguments[i]);
        if (intval > largest)
            largest = intval;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method like that:

```
var max = function(){
    var p = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        p.push(parseInt(arguments[i]) || null);
    return Math.max.apply(Math.max, p);
}

console.log(max(1, 2, "123" ,"4", "null", "123123123"))
```

You can play with [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5fXv/)

Advanced example

```
var max = function(){
    var p = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        p.push(parseInt(arguments[i]) || null);
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math.max, p);
}

var number = prompt("Enter the number of input");
if(parseInt(number) != NaN){
    var l = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(number); i++){
        var e = prompt("Enter number #" + (i+1));
        l.push(e);
    }
    alert("Largest number is " + max.apply(null, l));
}
```

Play with advanced [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5fXv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parseInt to ensure that the numbers are treated as numbers and then the ordering is as you expect.

```
function Max(num1,num2,num3)
{
 var largest=arguments[num1,num2,num3]
 for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
 {
  var i1 = parseInt(num1);
  var i2 = parseInt(num2);
  var i3 = parseInt(num3);
  if((i1>i2)&&(i1>i3))
  largest=i1
  else if((i2>i1)&&(i2>i3))
  largest=i2
  else
  largest=i3
 }
 return(largest)
}
document.write("</br>")
var num1 = prompt("Enter first number"," ")
var num2 = prompt("Enter second number"," ")
var num3 = prompt("Enter third number"," ")
var large = Max(num1,num2,num3)
document.write("You entered",num1,",",num2,",",num3)
document.write("</br>")
document.write("The largest number is :",large)
```