# How can I find all indexes of the max value of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I am trying to find a way to get the max value of an array, then find all indexes of that value. I want to repeat this two more times.

I have an array of 8 scores. I want to find all first places, all second places, and all third places.

```
Array = [0, 400, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 200]
```

1st place indexes: 1, 3

2nd place indexes: 2, 4

3rd place indexes: 5, 7

How can I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Where is the code that you need help with?

Comment: My guess: you're going to need a loop...

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. I thought this might be sufficient information. I have the array. I don't how to write the javascript to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: The point RobG and I were making is that you don't seem to have made any attempt to code this on your own. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) And in what format would you like the resulting indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the trick:

```
var scores = [0, 400, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 200];

// make a working copy, so that we can change the working copy
// while doing the calculations without changing the original array
var working = scores.slice(0),
    max,
    indices,
    numberOfPlaces = 3,
    results = []; 

for (var p = 0; p < numberOfPlaces; p++) {
    max = Math.max.apply(null, working);
    indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < working.length; i++)
        if (working[i] === max && working[i] > Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
            indices.push(i);
            working[i] = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
    results.push(indices);
}
```

For your input `results` will be `[[1,3], [2,4], [5,7]]`. That is, `results[0]` will hold the first place indices, `results[1]` will hold the second place indices, and so on.

If you later decided you only wanted the first two places, or your wanted the first five, just change the `numberOfPlaces` variable.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. I will be trying this in my code.  I will try to add more code in my future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the scores are not big numbers, you can build a hash of "score to indexes", and then sort by keys, and print out the indexes:

the running sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmA35/2/

the code:

```
var arr = [0, 400, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 200];
var hashValueToPosition = {};
var i;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    hashValueToPosition[arr[i]] = (hashValueToPosition[arr[i]] || []);
    hashValueToPosition[arr[i]].push(i);
}

// see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object  for Object.keys or the following:
var getKeys = function(obj){
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in obj){
      keys.push(key);
   }
   return keys;
}

var arrMaxToMinScores = getKeys(hashValueToPosition).sort().reverse();

for (i = 0; i < arrMaxToMinScores.length; i++) {
    $("body").append("<pre>" + arrMaxToMinScores[i] + ": " + JSON.stringify(hashValueToPosition[arrMaxToMinScores[i]]) + "</pre>");
}
```

Comment: +1. I like this solution, but what do you mean by "Assuming the scores are not big numbers"? How big is too big?

Answer (score 0):

```
function awardPrizes(arr){
    var L= arr.length, prizes= [[], [], []], n;

    // save the three highest scores in scores array:
    // eg: [400,300,200]

    var scores= arr.slice().filter(function(n, i){
        return arr.indexOf(n)== i;
    }).sort(function(a, b){ return b-a}).slice(0, 3);

    //put the high scoring indexes in the relevant prizes array:

    arr.forEach(function(itm, i){
        n= scores.indexOf(itm);
        if(n!= -1) prizes[n].push(i);
    });
    return prizes;
    //[first group,second group,third group]

}
var data= awardPrizes([0, 400, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 200]);


/*  returned value: (Array)
[
    [1, 3],
    [2, 4],
    [5, 7]
]
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

Like functional programming?

```
a={};[0, 400, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 200].forEach(
    (el,i) => a[el]? a[el].push(i) : a[el]=[i]
);
Object.keys(a).sort().reverse().map(k => [Number(k),a[k].sort()])
```

Basically hashes all the values, then goes through the keys in descending order, mentioning the indexes in ascending order. Ex:

```
[
    [400,[1,3]],
    [300,[2,4]],
    [200,[5,7]],
    [100,[6]],
    [0,[0]]
]
```