# Extract largest numbers from an array

Tags: javascript, range

```
var set = new Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15);
```

I need to extract largest numbers from this kind of set.
 How many numbers are extracted doesn't matter
but they need to have significant difference with the unextracted ones.

So in this set I should get `[9, 12, 15]`

I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Define significant difference

Comment: May be the extracted ones should fall in kind of third quartile? And if the set contains only two elements then the upper half.

Comment: What's your equation to determine this significant difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: I'd say you use `.sort()` to sort the array, then take however many you want off one end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aternative way of choosing largest numbers:

```
var set = new Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15);

function getHighNums(arr,percentage,fillpercentage){
    var perc=0;
    var sorted=arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b});
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) total+=arr[i];
    for(var j=sorted.length-1;j>=0;j--){
        perc+=sorted[j]/total*100;
        if(fillpercentage){
            if(perc > percentage) return sorted.slice(j,sorted.length);
        }else{ 
            if(sorted[j]/total*100 < percentage) return sorted.slice(j+1,sorted.length);
        }
    }
    return sorted;

}

console.log(getHighNums(set, 10, false))//9,12,15
console.log(getHighNums(set, 50, true))//12,15
```

The first line gets all numbers that are at least 10% of sum of array value. Sum of array= `1+2+1+2+3+9+12+15=45` so it picks numbers `> 4.5`

The second line gets numbers until their sum is at least 50% of the total sum of the array. So as sum of array `=45`, it will pick highest numbers until their sum is `> 22.5`

Answer (score 4):

If, as you seem to indicate in a comment to your question, you just want those greater than the third quartile, it's easy.

Simply create a *sorted* list of the `N` numbers and then get those above the `3N/4` index position.

You can use [`Array.sort()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) to sort the array, [`Array.length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) to get the length and [`Array.slice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to extract a slice of the array.

For example, the following code:

```
var set = new Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15);
document.write(set);

set.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
document.write('<br>');
document.write(set);

var len = set.length;
document.write('<br>');
document.write(len);

var topQ = set.slice (3*len/4);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(topQ);
```

outputs the unsorted and sorted list, the length, and the top 25%:

```
1,2,1,2,3,9,12,15
1,1,2,2,3,9,12,15
8
12,15
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution to get max 3 number of max value

```
 var set = new Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15);


function getmax(index)
{ return set.sort(function(a,b){return b-a;})[index];

}

var topmax = new Array(
getmax(2),getmax(1),getmax(0)
)


console.log(topmax);
```

[JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/sizajara/1/)

**EDITED**

```
var set = new Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15);

 set.sort(function(a,b){return b-a;});



document.write(set[2],set[1],set[0]);
```

Comment: That seems rather inefficient, sorting the array every time you want to extract a value. Surely you could sort it once then extract a slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. (look for value that is less than CV - CV / I; Where CV - current value; I - some coefficient)

Javascript

```
var data = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 15],
    index = 3,
    i;

function getMaximums(data, index){
    data = data.sort(function(a, b){return a < b});

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(!data[i + 1] || (data[i] - data[i] / index) > data[i + 1]) return data.splice(0, i + 1);
    }
}

console.log(getMaximums(data, index));
```