# JavaScript coding to get the highest value

Tags: javascript, arrays

We having an array eg: `a[]`, I need to pass some values randomly in to this, eg:`a[98,75,65,102,35,85,6]`.

If I subtract the value from before element `(65-75=-10)`, coming to `98` we can't subtract it because we are not having the previous element, so we can leave it. When we subtract all the element with its previous number we will get some value, I need to display that highest value in the output.

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: also the EXACT expected output for the example input - not sure why you show 7 element array, and only discuss the 3rd, 2nd and 1st elements in that order ... no idea what you expect the **result** to be

Comment: Is your desired output the largest difference between any two adjacent numbers in the array, or the largest difference between the biggest and smallest numbers in the array, or...? What would the output be for the array you show?

Comment: 98 cannot be subtract because it is not having the previous element,75-98= -23,65-75= -10, 102-65 = 37, 35-102 = -67...,so now the values that what i got isa[-23,-10,37,-67..], i want to print the biggest number in this array.

Answer (score 0):

At first we have arrary `a`

```
var a = [98,75,65,102,35,85,6];
```

and lets declare the new array `a1`:

```
var a1 = [];
```

lets run a loop that fill this array by subtracting each element(except first element) with previous element.

```
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    a1.push(a[i-1]-a[i]);
}
```

then we will get a1 as:

```
a1 = [23, 10, -37, 67, -50, 79];
```

Thus, we can apply different method to get max from array as in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array) and one that is prefer is

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, a1);
```

At last, `max` is `79`

Hope, this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code:

```
var arr = [98, 75, 65, 102, 35, 85, 6];
var max = undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    var dif = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
    if (max === undefined || dif > max) {
        max = dif;
    }
}
console.log(max);
```

For convenience please check this in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/nn7dxpp0/).

Comment: Small doubt...if i don't know the array elements then how to pass a values in array

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical application for "reduce"--we are trying to reduce an array down to a single number. The basic form is

```
a.reduce(findLargestDifference)
```

Where `findLargestDifference` is a function which is passed the most recent reduced value, the element, the index, and the original array:

```
function findLargestDifference(cur, elt, idx, arr) {
  var diff = arr[idx-1] - elt;
  return idx === 1 ? diff : diff > cur ? diff : cur;
}
```