# Find the array with the largest number in a 2d array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

This is my attempt and it works fine, but I need to return the array containing the largest number, not the largest number itself.

Also, I want to know if there is a way to use deep-equal to compare inner arrays in 2D arrays.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var largest = [0][0];
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
   if (arr[i][j] > largest) {
    largest = arr[i][j];
   }
  }
 }

 return largest;

}

var largest = largestOfFour([
 [4, 5, 1, 3],
 [13, 27, 18, 26],
 [32, 35, 37, 39],
 [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Comment: @durbnpoisn this is asking how to find the array with the largest number in a 2D array with Javascript, not the largest number of a (1D) array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another variable and store the `arr[i]` array at the same time that you note the biggest number. You could remove `largest` variable if you only need the largest array (or replace `largestOrigin` by it).

**JavaScript**

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var largest = 0,
        largestOrigin = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] > largest){
                largest = arr[i][j];
                largestOrigin = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return largestOrigin;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
// Returns  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
```

[**JSFiddle** (live demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/8nf1cwkd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

just for fun using new array methods:

```
  function largestOfFour(r){
    var biggest=Math.max.apply(null, r.join(",").split(",")); //merge arrays then find largest number in flat
    return  r.find( /./.test, RegExp("\\b"+biggest+"\\b") ); // find by matching element of sub-array to biggest flat array value
  }


  var largest=largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
  alert(largest); // shows "1000, 1001, 857, 1"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I guess that is a little complex for me. I am still learning JavaScript so loops are the easiest way for me at least for now.

Comment: Additionally, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980012/7438857, using a loop is actually more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to find largest numbers in 2D array

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(n => Math.max(...n));
}
```

### Function explanation:

1. Array's `map` method will iterate and execute the callback on each item and populate the array with the computed value
2. Math's `max` method will get the biggest value in the given set of values
3. Once the max value computed it will be pushed to the array `arr`

Comment: add more description

Comment: Easy way to find largest numbers in 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on those freecodecamp bonfires :). Here was my solution:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
 var max = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     max.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]));
  }

  return max;
}
```