# How to get biggest number in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textarea like this:

```
<textarea>
this is a test [1] also this [2] is a test
and again [3] this is a test
</textarea>
```

Now I need to get the biggest number which is in `[]`. In this case I need to get `3`. How can I do that?

Comment: get the value of the textarea in a string variable, extract the values in [] using a regex, parse them to numbers and then sort them and get the highest value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
var result = Math.max.apply(Math, textarea.value.match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
```

Breaking it up:

```
textarea.value.match(/\d+/g)
```

Gets you an array of numbers as strings.

```
.map(Number)
```

Maps each entry of the array from a string to a number.

```
Math.max.apply
```

Calls `Math.max` with `this` as `Math` and as parameters the mapped array.

**Edit**: I didn't realize what you needed had to be in between brackets. You'll need to use a capture group for that and it's a little bit more complicated now.

```
var reg = /\[(\d+)\]/g, numberStrings = [ ], match;
while((match = reg.exec(textarea.value)) !== null){
    numberStrings.push(match[1]);
}

var result = Math.max.apply(Math, numberStrings.map(Number));
```

It's a little bit more tricky to get the array of strings with the numbers.

Another alternative, without using a capture group:

```
var numbersInBrackets = textarea.value.match(/\[\d+\]/g);
var numbers = numbersInBrackets.map(function(x) {
    return Number(x.substring(1, x.length - 1));
});
var result = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
```

Comment: great explanation ... well beyond *"try this"* +1

Comment: One issue with this approach is that it does not get the numbers inside `[...]`. It will consider all others if they are present. The general idea is great, just a couple more lines are required to get the right numbers.

Comment: I see, I'll add a note for that.

Comment: @MinusFour Thank you ...waiting for your edit .. I think you have to edit your regex ...

Comment: `.map(Number)` is not necessary. According to the [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math.max): _... calls ToNumber on each of the arguments_

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as MinusFour's solution. Uses jQuery but could easily be done without.

```
var content = $('textarea').val();
var contentArr = content.split(' ');
var nums = [];

for (var i = 0; i < contentArr.length; i++) {
  var txt = contentArr[i];
    if (txt.match(/[\d]/)) {
    nums.push(Number(txt.slice(1,-1)));
  }
}

// Max number is Math.max.apply(null, nums)
```

Full working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/bw1pc1d4/).

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to find the biggest `[number]` in any string :

```
var biggestNumber = function(str) {
    var pattern = /\[([0-9]+)\]/g, match, biggest = 0;

    while ((match = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (match.index === pattern.lastIndex) {
            pattern.lastIndex++;
        }
        match[1] = parseInt(match[1]);
        if(biggest < match[1]) {
            biggest = match[1];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

---

## DEMO

The following demo calculates the biggest number in your textarea every time you click the button.

It allows you to play around with the textarea and re-test the function with a different text.

```js
var biggestNumber = function(str) {
    var pattern = /\[([0-9]+)\]/g, match, biggest = 0;

    while ((match = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (match.index === pattern.lastIndex) {
            pattern.lastIndex++;
        }
        match[1] = parseInt(match[1]);
        if(biggest < match[1]) {
            biggest = match[1];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(biggestNumber(document.getElementById("myTextArea").value));
});
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="myTextArea">
this is a test [1] also this [2] is a test
and again [3] this is a test
    </textarea>
</div>

<div>
   <button id="myButton">Try me</button>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/camtcupu/4/)!

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform 2 actions:

- Get all the `[(numbers)]` with [`\[(\d+)]` regex](https://regex101.com/r/uZ3zW0/1)
- Get the max value from the resulting array (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379556/3832970))

```js
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
var re = /\[(\d+)]/g;
var str = 'this is a test [1] also this [2] is a test\nand again [3] this is a test';
var numbers = [] 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  numbers.push(Number(m[1]));
}
document.write(Array.max(numbers));
```