# How can I transfer every line which starts with specific patterns to the end of the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = " this is a [link][1]
            [1]: http://example.com
            and this is a [good website][2] in my opinion
            [2]: http://goodwebsite.com
            [3]: http://example.com/fsadf.jpg
            [![this is a photo][3]][3]
            and there is some text hare ..! ";
```

Now I want this:

```
var newstr = "this is a [link][1]
              and this is a [good website][2] in my opinion
              [![this is a photo][3]][3]
              and there is some text hare ..!


                [1]: http://example.com
                [2]: http://goodwebsite.com
                [3]: http://example.com/fsadf.jpg"
```

How can I do that?

---

In reality, that variable `str` is the value of a textarea ... and I'm trying to create a markdown editor .. So what I want is exactly the same with what SO's textarea does.

---

Here is my try:

`/^(\[[0-9]*]:.*$)/g`  to select `[any digit]:` in the first of line

And I think I should create a group for that using `()` and then replace it with `\n\n $1`

Comment: Where has the `and there is some text hare ..!` gone?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
var re = /^(\[[0-9]*]:)\s*(.*)\r?\n?/gm;                // Regex declaration
var str = 'this is a [link][1]\n[1]: http://example.com\nand this is a [good website][2] in my opinion\n[2]: http://goodwebsite.com\n[3]: http://example.com/fsadf.jpg\n[![this is a photo][3]][3]\nand there is some text hare ..!';
var links = [];                                      // Array for the links
var result = str.replace(re, function (m, g1, g2) {  // Removing the links
  links.push("  " + g1 + " " + g2);                        // and saving inside callback
 return "";                                   // Removal happens here 
});
var to_add = links.join("\n");                   // Join the links into a string
document.getElementById("tinput").value = result + "\n\n\n" + to_add; // Display
```

```html
<textarea id="tinput"></textarea>
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN2rJ7/1) at regex101.com.

**Regex explanation**:

- `^` - start of line (due to the `/m` modifier)
- `(\[[0-9]*]:)` - Group 1 (referred to as `g1` in the replace callback) matching...

  - `\[` - opening square bracket
  - `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
  - `]` -  closing square bracket
  - `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(.*)` - Group 2 matching (`g2`) zero or more characters other than newline
- `\r?\n?` - one or zero `\r` followed by one or zero `\n`
- `/gm` - define global search and replace and `^` matches line start instead of string start

Comment: Perfect ..! Just one thing .. How can I add two spaces behind `[1]:`, `[2]:`, `[3]:` ?

Comment: Use 2 capturing groups.

Comment: Very thanks, but have you updated your fiddle? because there isn't two spaces before `[number]:` in your fiddle

Comment: Aha, you say *before* now, I understood *behind* as *after* :) I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And as a consult: When user clicks of link-icon *(in the toolbar of editor)*, I will add a link-pattern for him .. Now I need to create a new number of his new link, like `[4]` *(if the last link is `[3]`)*. So [I get the biggest number of textarea-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912624/how-to-get-biggest-number-in-textarea#34912697) and increase it and use it for new link. Is this algorithm ok? Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: If you keep the array of links on a global level, you won't have to look for the "biggest number", you will have it in `links.length`.

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, Just one thing, your regex works as well, all fine .. But I think we can add `$` to make it more accurate. I mean: select `[anydigit]:` for first of line until end of that line `$`. Am I right? or `$` is useless in this case?

Comment: `.` does not match a newline. The greedy `.*` subpattern will always match up to the end of the line and stop at the first newline symbol. Thus, it is redundant.

Comment: May you please tell me how can I define this `\s*` as just {zero-space or one-space or - two-spaces or three-spaces}? *(A range between 0-3 spaces)*

Comment: [*Limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) to the rescue: `\s{0,3}` will match 0 to 3 whitespaces.

Comment: I don't know how should I say *thanks* :-) You answer quickly .. and always know the answer of my question, and always you are there!, Lemme ask do you need sleep? `;-)` ...! Anyway thanks buddy, I learned a lot of things from you today ..

Comment: I am about to go to bed. You may upvote one of my other [JS answers that have positive votes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3832970%20%5bjavascript%5d%20%5bregex%5d) to thank for my extra hints  :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
strLinksArray = str.match(/(\[\d+\]\:\s*[^\s\n]+)/g);
strWithoutLinks = str.replace(/(\[\d+\]\:\s*[^\s\n]+)/g, ''); //removed all links
```

Here you will get links as array and string without links then do whatever changes you want.

Comment: emm I don't know I can use it or not, but your solution seems useful ..! +1