# Picking the largest number in an array

Tags: javascript

> Write a single function that outputs the “largest” phone number in an input array (if multiple numbers are equally large, return the last one). Assume that the phone numbers are strings of 10 digits separated by dashes.

I wrote a function to answer the questions above. It comes out undefined. can someone help me find the error please. I feel that i am close to the answer.

```js
var largestNumber = function(strings) {
  var ints = strings.map(function(el) {
    return el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
      return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
  });

  console.log(ints);

  var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, ints);
  return strings[ints.lastIndexOf(largest)];
};

console.log(largestNumber(['111-111-1111', '111-111-1112', '111-111-1113']));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: You can't use two returns statements the way you are. The second one will never get encountered.

Comment: @j08691 There is only one `return` statements.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Actually there are three, but the sloppy code formatting made it look like there were two at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

```
ints.lastIndexOf(largest)
```

This part searches for the last occurence of `largest` in `ints`. However, `largest` will always be a number, but `ints` contains only strings. Therefore, the number isn’t found and `undefined` is returned. To fix this, convert `largest` back to a string:

```
ints.lastIndexOf(largest.toString())
```

Also, you don’t need to split the strings and concatenate them back together.

This code is working:

```js
var largestNumber = function(strings) {
  var ints = strings.map(function(el) {
    return el.replace(/-/g, '');
  });

  console.log(ints);

  var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, ints);

  return strings[ints.lastIndexOf(largest.toString())];
};

console.log(largestNumber(['111-111-1111', '111-111-1112', '111-111-1113']));
```

Alternatively, you could map the strings to numbers:

```
var ints = strings.map(function(el) {
  return Number(el.replace(/-/g, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `reduce()` why not use one `reduce()` to return the highest

```js
var largestNumber = function(strings) {
    return strings.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
        return +currentValue.replace(/-/g,'') > 
               +previousValue.replace(/-/g,'') ? currentValue : previousValue;
    });
};

alert(largestNumber(['111-111-1111', '111-111-1112', '111-111-1113']));
```