# How to simulating the aggregate functions avg, sum, max, min, and count on PouchDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, pouchdb, database, nosql

Does anyone know how to create aggregate functions, for example avg, sum, max and min on PouchDB database. I created a simple application to test the PouchDB. I'm still not figured out how to run these commands. Thanks in advance.

For example. How do you get the highest, lowest or average for the "number" field?

> My main Ionic 2 component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';
declare var require: any;
var pouch = require('pouchdb');
var pouchFind = require('pouchdb-find');
@Component({
    template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = HomePage;
    db: any;
    value: any;
    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });
        pouch.plugin(pouchFind);
        this.db = new pouch('friendsdb');
        let docs = [
            {
                '_id': '1',
                'number': 10,
                'values': '1, 2, 3',
                'loto': 'fooloto'
            },
            {
                '_id': '2',
                'number': 12,
                'values': '4, 7, 9',
                'loto': 'barloto'
            },
            {
                '_id': '3',
                'number': 13,
                'values': '9, 4, 5',
                'loto': 'fooloto'
            }
        ];
        this.db.bulkDocs(docs).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: Avg of what? Sum of what? Max and min of what? Do you want to store those values in a variable (or just want to `console.log` them)?

Comment: It could be displayed on the console. For example, larger, smaller, sum, avg value stored in the "number" field.
For example, the largest value stored in the "number" is => 'number': 13. This can be displayed on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map`/`reduce` functions [of the `db.query()` method from PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) to get the average, sum, largest or any other kind of aggregation of the docs.

I have created a [**demo JSBin fiddle with a running example**](http://jsbin.com/cupozejiha/edit?html,js,output). I added the explanation of the functions directly into the code (below) as comments, as I thought it'd be simpler.

```
var db = new PouchDB('friendsdb');
var docs = [
      {'_id': '1', 'number': 10, 'values': '1, 2, 3', 'loto': 'fooloto'},
      {'_id': '2', 'number': 12, 'values': '4, 7, 9', 'loto': 'barloto'},
      {'_id': '3', 'number': 13, 'values': '9, 4, 5', 'loto': 'fooloto'}
];

db.bulkDocs(docs).then(function(result) {
  querySum();
  queryLargest();
  querySmallest();
  queryAverage();
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

function querySum() {
  function map(doc) {
    // the function emit(key, value) takes two arguments
    // the key (first) arguments will be sent as an array to the reduce() function as KEYS
    // the value (second) arguments will be sent as an array to the reduce() function as VALUES
    emit(doc._id, doc.number);
  }
  function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
    // keys:
    //   here the keys arg will be an array containing everything that was emitted as key in the map function...
    //   ...plus the ID of each doc (that is included automatically by PouchDB/CouchDB).
    //   So each element of the keys array will be an array of [keySentToTheEmitFunction, _idOfTheDoc]
    //
    // values
    //   will be an array of the values emitted as value
    console.info('keys ', JSON.stringify(keys));
    console.info('values ', JSON.stringify(values));
    // check for more info: http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchapp/views/intro.html


    // So, since we want the sum, we can just sum all items of the values array
    // (there are several ways to sum an array, I'm just using vanilla for to keep it simple)
    var i = 0, totalSum = 0;
    for(; i < values.length; i++){
        totalSum += values[i];
    }
    return totalSum;
  }
  db.query({map: map, reduce: reduce}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('sum is ' + response.rows[0].value);
  });
}

function queryLargest() {
  function map(doc) {
    emit(doc._id, doc.number);
  }
  function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
    // everything same as before (see querySum() above)
    // so, this time we want the larger element of the values array

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1379560/1850609
    return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
  }
  db.query({map: map, reduce: reduce}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('largest is ' + response.rows[0].value);
  });
}

function querySmallest() {
  function map(doc) {
    emit(doc._id, doc.number);
  }
  function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
    // all the same... now the looking for the min
    return Math.min.apply(Math, values);
  }
  db.query({map: map, reduce: reduce}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('smallest is ' + response.rows[0].value);
  });
}

function queryAverage() {
  function map(doc) {
    emit(doc._id, doc.number);
  }
  function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
    // now simply calculating the average
    var i = 0, totalSum = 0;
    for(; i < values.length; i++){
        totalSum += values[i];
    }
    return totalSum/values.length;
  }
  db.query({map: map, reduce: reduce}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('average is ' + response.rows[0].value);
  });
}
```

**Note:** This is just one way to do it. There are several other possibilities (not emitting IDs as keys, using groups and different reduce functions, using built-in reduce functions, such as _sum, ...), I just thought this was the simpler alternative generally speaking.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, I had already lost hope! Thank you so much, @acdcjunior

Answer (score 4):

The highest and lowest values of the numbers fields are retrievable using the built-in **_stats** reduce function.

```
var myMapReduceFun = {
  map: function (doc) {
    emit(doc._id, doc.number);
  },
  reduce: '_stats'
};

db.query(myMapReduceFun, {reduce: true}).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
}).catch(function (err) {
  // handle errors
});
```

The result looks similar to this:

```
{"sum":35,"count":3,"min":10,"max":13,"sumsqr":214}
```

The highest value is in the "max"-field, the lowest in the "min"-field. Now you just have to calculate your desired average, for example the mean average:

```
var meanAverage = result.sum / result.count;
```

Other [built-in reduce functions](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) in PouchDB are _count and _sum.

The [PouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) says the following about reduce functions:

> Tip: if you’re not using a built-in, you’re probably doing it wrong.

Comment: That's possibly the worst tip I've ever seen in documentation.

They also say, "Warning: advanced API. The map/reduce API is designed for cases that are too complex for Mango queries."  Given that Mango queries still don't have any any aggregation features, that makes all but the simplest of queries "too complex" for Mango queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `views` in PouchDB for problems like this.

https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html

It is possible to create a stored view that allows you to requery the same index multiple times: meaning while the first time through is slow (full scan), later queries will be much faster as the data has already been indexed.

```
var db = new PouchDB('friendsdb');

var view = {
  '_id':'_design/metrics',
  'views':{
    'metrics':{
      'map':function(doc){
        // collect up all the data we are looking for
        emit(doc._id, doc.number);
      }.toString(),
      'reduce':function(keys, values, rereduce){
        var metrics = {
          sum:0,
          max:Number.MIN_VALUE,
          min:Number.MAX_VALUE,
          count:0
        };
        // aggregate up the values
        for(var i=values.length-1; i>=0; i--){
          var v = values[i];
          metrics.sum += v;
          metrics.max = (metrics.max < v) ? v : metrics.max;
          metrics.min = (metrics.min < v) ? metrics.min : v;
          metrics.count += v.count || 1;
        }
        metrics.avg = metrics.sum/metrics.count;
        return metrics;
      }.toString()
    }
  }
};

// alternately you could use a built in reduce
// if one already exists for the aggregation 
// you are looking for
//view.reduce = '_stats';

// note the addition of the view
var docs = [view
  ,{'_id':'1','number':10,'values':[1,2,3],'loto':'fooloto'}
  ,{'_id':'2','number':12,'values':[4,7,9],'loto':'barloto'}
  ,{'_id':'3','number':13,'values':[9,4,5],'loto':'fooloto'}
];

db.bulkDocs(docs).then(function(result) {
  db.query('metrics',{reduce:true},function(err, response) {
    var m = response.rows[0].value;
    console.log('smallest.: ' + m.min);
    console.log('largest..: ' + m.max);
    console.log('average..: ' + m.avg);
    console.log('count....: ' + m.count);
    console.log('Total ...: ' + m.sum);
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Note the addition of the view to the data you load into your database, as well as the fact that the map and reduce are requried to be converted to strings (the `.toString()` at the end of the function)