# Conditional statement inside a Math.min or a Math.max in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, max, conditional-statements, min

I want to Math.min a few **Date** values (e.g. var1.getTime(), var2.getTime(), and var3.getTime()). However, before I can use .getTime() on them, I need to make sure they exist (so the script doesn't crash).

If one of the variables doesn't exist I still want to get the Math.min of the other variables that exist.

Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Put your date values into an array then follow ^ question.

Comment: What's the behavior if none of them exist?

Comment: @Mike C Yes, but how do you make sure they exist before you put them in the Array? Because, if one of them don't exist .getTime() will make the script crash. And how do you .getTime() them before you Math.min them ?

Comment: @ScottSauyet The behavior should be that nothing happens.

Comment: @Emilio The same way that you check for anything. Only add them to the array of `someVar instanceof Date`.

Comment: @Emilio: [Nothing at all?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf7rntVimhw)  The code that gives you back the max/min Date or timestamp -- does it return nothing?  `null`?  Throw an exception?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I mean, I'm fine with undefined or null.

Comment: Have you got a code snippet to share so we can give you useful advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store your date variables in an array, you can use `filter` to remove non-`Date` objects and pass that to `Math.min.apply` or `Math.max.apply`

```
const dates = [var1, var2, var3];
const min = Math.min(...dates.filter(date => date instanceof Date));
```

Or non-ECMAScript 6:

```
var dates = [var1, var2, var3];
var min = Math.min.apply(null, dates.filter(function(date) {
  return date instanceof Date;
}));
```

Comment: Yeah, but you still need to .getTime()  them before you can Math.min them ?  How do you do that?

Comment: No you don't, dates are implicitly converted to numbers (their timestamp value) when mathematical operations are performed on them: `+new Date()`

Comment: @RobM.  I see you updated the es6 code. Should we also update the non-es6 code or not? Thanks

Comment: @Emilio, nope, es6 doesn't need `.apply` because of the spread operator, prior to es6 `.apply` was the way to achieve this

Comment: Great answer! I would just add a "new Date" to your answer in order to get back a date value.

So, for non-es6, 

var dates = [var1, var2, var3];
var min = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates.filter(function(date) {
  return date instanceof Date;
})));