# Find max from array of char and number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like
    `['VS', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'VE']`

I am using substring to get second part which returns me 
    `'S', '1', '2', '3', 'E'`

I have to find the max integer value which will be `3` in this case. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array) solution but I am geting NaN.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to filter out the none numeric characters first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the casted value for truthyness and use a zero as default value.

> ```
> +s[1] || 0
>
>  s[1]       take the character at index 1
> +           use unary plus for converting string to number, this could return NaN
>       || 0  in this case take zero instead of the falsey value, like NaN
> ```

```js
var array = ['VS', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'VE'],
    max = Math.max(...array.map(s => +s[1] || 0));

console.log(max);
```

ES5

```js
var array = ['VS', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'VE'],
    max = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(function (s) { return +s[1] || 0; }));

console.log(max);
```

Comment: what +s[1] doing here? can you please explain.

Comment: I would use something like `parseInt()` instead. To make the code more readable

Comment: @αƞjiβ the + forces the result to be a number, s[1] is second element of string (a string is an array of characters).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the values are still strings after you get rid of the first char.

```js
var ary = ['VS', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'VE'];

var ary2 = ary.map(function(val){
  // Get the second character and convert to a number if possible
  // ruturn that number or null
  return parseInt(val.charAt(1)) || null;
});

// Now, the function will work
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

console.log(Array.max(ary2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove any non-numbers. This should return an array containing only numbers of your array.

```
['S','1','2','3','E'].filter((item) => parseInt(item)).map((item) => parseInt(item))
```

will return:

```
 [1, 2, 3]
```