# I cant solve this: to find the minimum number from an array that is input through prompt()

Tags: javascript, arrays, min, prompt, minimum

I cant solve this homework that needs to ask the user to enter student marks and output the minimum mark of the student, can someone please help me solve this problem:

```
    <script>
 function getMarks() {
    var marks = prompt('Type the students marks, seperate each student mark with comma, do not write the percentage mark % .').split(',');
    return marks;
  }
  var studentMarks = getMarks();
  var arrayLength = studentMarks.length;
  var studentNumber = 0;
  var msg = '';
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    studentNumber = (i + 1);
    msg += 'student ' + studentNumber + ': ';
    msg +=  studentMarks[i] + '%' + '<br />';
  } document.getElementById('marks').innerHTML = msg; document.getElementById('marke').innerHTML = math.min.apply(null, studentMarks) + '%';
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do that in the following way:

```js
function getMarks() {
  var marks = prompt('Type the students marks, seperate each student mark with comma, do not write the percentage mark % .');
  return marks.split(',').map(n => Number(n));
}

var marksArray = getMarks();
var studentMarks = Math.min(...marksArray);
var position = marksArray.indexOf(studentMarks);
var msg = 'Student ' + Number(position + 1) + ': ';
document.getElementById('marks').innerHTML = msg + studentMarks +  '%';
```

```html
<p id="marks"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you but this asks me two times to prompt is there another method?

Comment: @itsjustme, `two times to prompt`  no.....it is not.....only a single prompt with comma separated number...