# using filter() method in javascript to find largest number in an array

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript ,can anyone tell me is it possible to find the largest number in an array, using filter() method ,exclusively filter() method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Can you sort it first?

Comment: Any attempt???????

Comment: Sort the array and take the `top`

Comment: filter() is the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Sorting would work but it's less efficient than simply finding the largest value in a single pass over the array.

Comment: @charlietfl This sounds like a puzzle question, not about how to do it the best way.

Answer (score 2):

I know this doesn't use filter(), but you can do it with a simple **sort() and return the last element**.

```js
var arr = [50,40,60,0,10,5];
var max = arr.sort((a,b)=> a-b)[arr.length-1]
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously filter is not the write function for that, but:

```
Math.max.apply(0, array);
```

If anyway you want to do this with filter, you can do something like this.

```
var arr = [...];
var a = arr[0];
var b = arr.filter(function(i){
  if (i > a) {
    a = i;
  }
  return i == a;
});
return b[b.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use filter try this:

```
var A = [-25, 110, 1000, 31, 1,2]/*Your Array*/, max=-Infinity;
A.filter(function(a,b,c){if(a>max)max=a;});
console.log(max);
```

else, this is another **simple** way:

```
console.log([-25, 110, 1000, 31, 1,2].sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0]);
```

Comment: if i am not wrong, a stands for elements of array ,b for index,c for array but what does d indicates

Comment: You are exactly right. d is extra. i forgot to remove it. simple and practical ways.