# How to make a loop read through an array of numbers and find the largest?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I understand that a loop repeats itself for a specified number of times, but how do I make so that it reads through the entire array and returns a certain value? I'm trying to return the largest value for two test questions, but the only result I'm getting is the first value of the array.

```
function question1(numberArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i = i + 1) {
    number = numberArray[i];
    return number;
  }
}

function testQuestion1() {
  let testArray = [10, 45, 33, 67, 433, 33];
  let answer1 = question1(testArray);
  if(question1(testArray) == 433) {
    console.log("Question 1:Found the largest");
  } else {
    console.log("Question1: For array ", testArray, " returned ", answer1, "Which is not the largest");
  }

  let testArray2 = [10, -900, 3000, 22, 33, 67, 433, 33];
  let answer2 = question1(testArray);
  if(question1(testArray2) == 3000) {
    console.log("Question 1: Found the largest");
  } else {
    console.log("Question 1: For array ", testArray2, " returned ", answer2, "Which is not the largest");
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364157/using-filter-method-in-javascript-to-find-largest-number-in-an-array

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question with language tag... Probably "javascript"...

Comment: Welcome!
`return` immediately exits the function.

Comment: Does my answer help you understand better?
If so, please accept it (by clicking accept), and up-vote (when you have 15+ reputation points).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with Array spread operator (also in link):

```
function myMax(numberArray) {
  return Math.max(...numberArray);
}
```

Using `for` loops and a `max` variable:

```
function myMax(numberArray) {
  var max=-Infinity;
  for(var i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++)
    if(numberArray[i]>max)
      max=numberArray[i];
  return max;
}
```

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function myMax(numberArray) {
  return numberArray.reduce((max, arrayItem)=>Math.max(max, arrayItem),-Infinity);
}
```

In all cases, if `numberArray` is empty, `-Infinity` will be returned.