# Find array max in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

Is this code correct to find the max from an array? There are other ways to find the max, however the requirements are to use "for" loop!Thanks! Full reqs : "Create an array with 10 numbers of your choice and a variable named max. **Assign 0 to max**. **In a for loop**, find the greatest number, assign it to max and write it in the console."

```
var numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var max = 0;
var arrLen = numArray.length;

for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] - numArray[arrLen - 1] >= 0) {
        max = numArray[i];
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(max);
}
```

Comment: You can simply use: `Math.max(...numArray)`

Comment: @palaѕн - *"...the requirements are to use "for" loop..."*.

Comment: ok, then maybe this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13794386/1823841)

Comment: I think this's a homework

Answer (score 2):

Approach it like this:

1. Start with `max` at `-Infinity`.
2. Inside the loop body, if `numArray[i]` is greater than `max`, set `max` to `numArray[i]`.
3. Show the result *after* the loop, since while the loop is still running, `max` may not be the maximum value yet.

At the end of the loop, `max` will contain the highest value in the array (or `-Infinity` if the array is empty).

---

Don't forget to declare **all** of your variables, including `i`.

Comment: Thnanks TJ, however requirements are: max= 0; & use a "for" loop. See below: "Create an array with 10 numbers of your choice and a variable named max. Assign 0 to max. In a for loop, find the greatest number, assign it to max and write it in the console." I know about max/ and function to sort the array, however I need to follow reqs. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexCocan - The suggestion above **is** following those requirements. (Other than if the requirements really require you to display `max` from *within* the loop, but I think that's a misreading as it makes no sense to do that...)

Comment: Thanks TJ, I used @ninascholz's solution, that works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the first element as max value and iterate from index one.

Then check and change max if a new maximum is found.

Do not forget to declare all variables (like `i`).

```js
var numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    max = numArray[0],
    arrLen = numArray.length,
    i;

for (i = 1; i < arrLen; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] > max) max = numArray[i];
}
console.log(max);
```

For having **all numbers greater than zero**, you could omit the assignment with first value and start index from zero.

```js
var numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    max = 0,
    arrLen = numArray.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] > max) max = numArray[i];
}
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, that works, however reqs are : max = 0; & use "for" loop. Thoughts? Thanks!