# Problem finding the largest element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I'm trying to write a function that receives a string of integers -I know this is not the ideal but it is how I was asked to do in an exercise-, puts them into an array an then gets the max value, minimal value, reads the entire array and counts how many times the max value was surpassed, and for last gives the position of the minimal value.

This is my code:

```
function performance(string) {

    let arrayScore = string.split(' ') //this part works as I tested before, the numbers of the string are correctly passed to the array

    let max = arrayScore[0]
    let min = arrayScore[0]

    let worstgame = 1
    let surpasses = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayScore.length; i++) {

        if (max < arrayScore[i]) {

            max = arrayScore[i]
            surpasses++
        }

        if (min > arrayScore[i]) {

            min = arrayScore[i]
            worstgame = i + 1
        }
    }

    //max = arrayScore.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
    //min = arrayScore.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b))

    return [surpasses, worstgame, max, min]
}

let score = "10 20 20 8 25 3 0 30 1"

console.log(performance(score)) /*here is the problem: the value 8 is attributed to 'max' -should be 30- and the number of surpasses returns 2 -should be 3-*/
```

I noticed that I can get the max value by using Math.max as an argument in reduce, but I still don't understand why counting the surpasses and the "if" condition for "max" in the "for" loop are not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: This was already asked,refer to the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613528/11781464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare numbers as strings, so `'30' < '8'` returns `true` :). Just use `Number.parseInt()` in order to get a number from a string (e.g. `Number.parseInt(max) < Number.parseInt(arrayScore[i])`)

Comment: Always supply a radix when using `parseInt` - from the docs: **Be careful—this does not default to 10!**

Comment: It's just easier to use the `+` operand here. `string.split(' ').map(Number)` is also more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

how you can do that

```
function performance(str) {
let scoreArr = str.split(' ').map(data => Number(data))
  return scoreArr.reduce((max, num) => {
           return max > num ? max : num; 
},0)
}

let score = "10 20 20 8 25 3 0 30 1"

console.log(performance(score))
// 30
```

Comment: If it's just a few numbers (~ fewer than thousands) you can use `Math.max(...str.split(' ').map(Number)`